# Apache mod_rewrite encoded URLs

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm working on a webpage that takes a URL as a parameter, and would like it to be easily indexed by search engines.  One requirement is that each URL appears as a directory.

My script is in the format:

```
myscript?url=<a url>&page=1
```

I'd like redirects to look something like:

```
lookup/<a url>/page:1/
```

The URL is predictably giving me trouble... I just want to tell mod_rewrite to select *anything* after "lookup/" and before "/page:".  Of course, nothing is ever as simple as it could be.

Here's the rewrite as it is now:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/lookup/(.+)/page:([0-9]+)(/?)$ /myscript?url=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

This works great, except it fails when URLs are properly encoded.  Take the example of "www.google.com/finance".  Here's what happens when I enter these URLs into my browser's address bar:

```
#this works
lookup/www.google.com/finance/page:1/

#this doesn't work.  url is cut off before the ?
lookup/www.google.com/finance?foo=bar/page:1/

#doesn't match rewrite at all!
lookup/www.google.com%2Ffinance/page:1/
```

I'm at a loss as to how to do this... Shouldn't (.+) select *anything*?  Do I need to tell mod_rewrite to ignore query parameters somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /lookup/([^\s]+)/page:([0-9]+)/[?\s]
RewriteRule ^/lookup/ /myscript?url=%1&page=%2 [L]
```

But you should really consider encoding that embedded URL properly instead of just guessing where it might end. So `/lookup/www.google.com/finance?foo=bar/page:1/` should be at least `/lookup/www.google.com/finance%3Ffoo=bar/page:1/` so the `?` is part of the URI path and not the indicator for the query.

Comment: I'll give this a shot.  Thanks for prompt answer!

Comment: No dice... apache doesn't like the %2F.  When I take it out, it works.

Comment: Just to be clear:  /lookup/www.google.com/finance%3Ffoo=bar/page:1/  works, but /lookup/www.google.com/finance%2Ffoo=bar/page:1/ does not.